# Increase variable in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I am a new in angular js. I want to count in ng-repeat like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="people in peoples">
{{ numberPeople++ }}. {{people.name}}
<div ng-repeat="repeople in people.families">
{{ numberPeople++ }}. {{repeople.name}}
</div>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="otherpeople in otherpeoples">
{{ numberPeople++ }}. {{otherpeople.name}}
</div>
{{ numberPeople }}
</div>
```

numberPepple will increase in each  ng-repeat
I see many question they said use $index but i use many ng-repeat

Comment: $index is tied to each ng-repeat, so what's wrong with $index?

Comment: This may give you some idea : http://stackoverflow.com/a/26781098/3279156

Comment: My problem is I can't count numberPeople in ng-repeat, I want display like this :
1. Tom, 2. Petter, 3. Ana

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ng-init**.
Tyr this:

```
  <div ng-repeat="people in peoples" ng-init="numberPeople=numberPeople+1">
     {{ numberPeople }}. {{people.name}}
     <div ng-repeat="repeople in people.families" ng-init="numberPeople=numberPeople+1">
       {{ numberPeople }}. {{repeople.name}}
      </div>
      </div>
       <div ng-repeat="otherpeople in otherpeoples" ng-init="numberPeople=numberPeople+1">
        {{ numberPeople }}. {{otherpeople.name}}
         </div>
        {{ numberPeople }}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular.forEach in JS file and set it in the model. Use that model in the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the `++` is not working, in your controller add `$scope.numberPeople = 0;` at the top and it will initialize the scope variable as an integer type and assign `0` to it. Then you can use `++`.